# Грамотная речь

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте.

Я работаю  администратором  в  крупной стоматологической  клинике. На днях я обзванивала  пациентов, напоминая им  о  предстоящем  визите. Выглядело это  следующим  образом: "ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ, ИВАН ИВАНОВИЧ. НАПОМИНАЮ ВАМ, ЧТО ЗАВТРА  У  ВАС ЗАПИСЬ НА 15 ЧАСОВ".

Это услышала врач-терапевт, сделала мне  категоричное  замечание, сказав, что фраза безграмотна. Настаивая  при этом на  примерно такой  фразе: "ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ, ИВАН ИВАнОВИЧ. НАПОМИНАЕМ ВАМ, ЧТО  ВЫ  ЗАПИСАНЫ  НА  ЗАВТРА  НА 15  ЧАСОВ".

Буду  очень  признательна, если  получу  аргументированный  ответ, и просто  счастлива, если  смогу  так  же  аргументированно  ей  возразить.

С  уважением, Алина.

Comment: @Птичка-говорун, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Какие  строгости,  прямо.  На  любую  из  этих  фраз  я  бы  ответил:  спасибо,  я  помню.  А  если  бы,  я  забыл  о  записи,  то  сказал  бы  большое  спасибо.  Причём,  я  думаю,  что  звонивший   обязательно  представился,  хотя  бы  тем,  что  уточнил  откуда  звонят.

Comment: Стиль,  конечно,  разговорный.  Но  он  же  в  разговоре  и  используется.  А  я  и  хочу,  чтоб  со  мной  разговаривали,  а  не  отправляли,  хоть  и  правильные,  но  дежурные  сообщения.  Мы  же  не  в  США,  всё-таки.

Answer (score 4):

Я не буду заниматься вопросами этикета - теми, что надо представляться, дожидаться ответного приветствия и проч. То, что описано по этому поводу в других ответах, правильно, но не имеет прямого отношения к русскому языку.

По сути. Ваш вариант неправилен уже потому, что вводит в заблуждение. Предложенный вам вариант "от терапевта" лучше, но тоже далеко не идеален с точки зрения русского языка.

Что значит "запись на такое-то время"? Прийти - и записаться? Так что не "запись" а "вы записаны". 
Во втором варианте - много лишних слов.

Идеальный диалог звучит как-то так.
*-**Здравствуйте. С вами говорит клиника "Зуб за Зуб" [менеджер Птичка-говорун]** (-если того требует корпоративный этикет).  



-Здравствуете.   



-**Это Такой Сякоевич Разэтакий?**   



-Да, слушаю.     



-**Хотим напомнить, что Вы записаны [на прием] к стоматологу в пятницу, 32 мартобря, на 15 часов.***

Дальше - по ситуации.

Оно и вежливее, и доходчивее.

Comment: )))... Спасибо. Даже  посмеялась  слегка. Во всяком  случае  у  меня  будет  возможность  зачитать это на  планерке. На которой, как  мне  потом рассказали , шли бурные  дебаты  по этому  поводу. И  что  самое  обидное - без меня. Мне  выдали  позже  текст на  бумажке,  который  я   показала  выше и  велели говорить четко  по нему. То, что второй  вариант  не безупречен  меня радует ))). Может быть, после того как  я  зачитаю  предложенные и на  мой  взгляд  комфортные  для  слуха  ответы,  категоричность  некоторых коллег  поутихнет. )))

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте И.И.! Говорит секретарь стоматологической клиники Алина. Хочу напомнить, что Ваш прием к доктору Фролову назначен на завтра в 15.00. Прошу Вас сообщить нам заблаговременно, если Вы будете вынуждены отменить прием.

Answer (score 1):

Его Величество Русский Язык

По-русски: грамотно и литературно, но сперва о двух обращениях: они просторечны, а просторечие признак неграмотности или пренебрежения в официальном общении.
Я последую примерам, которые используются здесь, в США,  врачами.
1. Здравствуйте Ив. Ив., *я Алина Круглова, медсестра/секретарь/помощник* *доктора Филатова. Напоминаю, завтра у Вас приём у ***стоматолога Сереброва на 15 часов.**** Если Вы не сможете прийти, позвоните нам, чтобы мы сумели выбрать с Вами время нового приёма.

Пояснение. *Звонящий называет себя и позицию в компании.* *Здесь стоит имя владельца компании или название компании (даже если в компании один доктор и один помощник). ***Здесь имя и позиция специалиста, даже если имя его уже упомянуто как владельца). В США больных по записи принимают также медсёстры, косметологи, протезисты, техники, гигиенисты этой же компании.**** До того как пациенты привыкли, обращение было более полным. Пациенту ещё объясняли, что своевременный отказ даст возможность в это время помочь другому нуждающему. Эта часть факультативна. 
или
2. Здравствуйте Ив. Ив., я Алина Круглова, медсестра/секретарь/помощник доктора Филатова. Напоминаю, на завтра Вы *записались на приём у стоматолога Сереброва в 15 часов. Если Вы не сможете прийти, позвоните нам, чтобы мы сумели выбрать с Вами время нового приёма.

Как маркетолог укажу. Важно *Вы записались - это Ваш выбор, Вы обязались прийти. Безличная фраза* Вы записаны звучит как упрашивание пациента.

Устал писать. Обращайтесь за помощью. Помогу.

Comment: Большое  спасибо. Пожалуй, Ваш ответ на  мой  вопрос более убедительный  и  понятный  для  меня.

Comment: Не здорово.  
Российский телефонный этикет несколько отличается от западного. если Вы такой набор текста вывалите без пауз, вас скорее всего сочтут за спам-бота.  
Обязательно надо дать клиенту опомниться и войти в разговор. И обязательно подтвердить, что он - это он. Русские не такие реактивные и не любят чересчур нахраспистых.  
С остальным - согласен.

Comment: Согласен с вами,  behemothus. Такой диалог несвойственен российской культуре.

Comment: У нас стоматологическая клиника не звонит, а рассылает СМС-напоминание.

Comment: >У нас стоматологическая клиника не звонит, а рассылает СМС-напоминание.  
  
Ну это не исключает, что где-то именно звонят. На домашний телефон, например. Мало ли, какие могут быть казусы.

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно, фраза выглядит неудачно. Но и у вашего коллеги фраза не лучше. Дело в том, что у вас смешение двух стилей: разговорного и письменного. У вашей коллеги на первый план выходит безличность: "напоминаем вам...", строгость изложения, что не свойственно разговорной речи. Кроме того два раза повторяется предлог "на".

Корректно (в письменной речи): Уважаемый Иван Иванович, напоминаем Вам, что завтра в 15:00 вам назначена запись на прием. В разговорной речи: Здравствуйте, Иван Иванович. Звоню вам напомнить, что завтра вы записаны на 3:00. Дело в том, что разговорная речь требует более коротких и простых конструкций.

Comment:  "вам назначена запись" -вы полагаете, это по-русски?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, исходная фраза просторечна, причём буквально её можно понять как такое предложение пациенту: "приходите завтра и запишитесь на 15 часов". Если пациент знает, что он уже записался или записан, он поймёт это как напоминание и не ошибётся, а если этой фразой ему впервые сообщают о записи, то он может неправильно понять, что ему нужно сделать. Фраза, которую Вам предложили, безупречна.

Comment: Если  он  не  записывался,  он  ответит  как  джентельмен: вы  ошиблись  номером,  мадам !

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый Иван Иванович! Ждем Вас на приеме у стоматолога завтра, в 15 часов.

Comment: Как маркетолог. Ждём Вас - плохо. Приём у врача здесь, в США, это правовой устный контракт, который обязателен для обеих сторон. Я знаю о редких случаях, когда специалисты (любые) отказывают в услугах тем, которые не соблюдают договор.   
Я не нашёл такого примера, но нашёл угрозы судебного процесса из-за нарушения обязательства. Врач имеет право по закону взыскать с пациента, не давшего знать заранее об отказе от согласованной услуги, денежный ущерб.